I have a QT5 app that does not work properly in Wayland how can I force it to use xwayland
I'm using LMMS, which is built with QT5 and it has a few problem with wayland.  Graphics are ok but quite a few mouse gestures are not working and windows-in-windows do not work properly.
e.g.
Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()

QtWaylandClient::QWaylandXdgSurface(0x64bdca7175b0) which does not match the current topmost grabbing popup

Is there any way to tell LMMS to use X and xwayland instead of wayland direct?  I am happy to compile the code to resolve this I have my own fork anyway.
I imagine wayland issues are ahem "security issues" i.e. not resolvable.
LMMS used to work, but I upgraded to 24.04 and I'm regretting it.

There is a env variable for that, just do this in your terminal
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb lmms
It will tell use Qt to use the X11 platform plugin, then if you are in a Wayland session it should work
